# How can I determine the tag or branch associated with a SVN working copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tags

I switched my SVN working copy to a particular branch (or tag). Or did I? I can't remember. How can I tell what tag or branch is associated with my working copy? If I do a commit, how do I know where it will go?

Answer (score 4):

On the command line, from your working directory, type:

```
svn info .
```

This will tell you a lot of information, including the URL path which should indicate tag/branch folders assuming your svn repo follows the normal conventions for tag and branch folders.

Comment: One reason I recommend having a command-line SVN client installed, even if you use Tortoise for most of your SVN needs

Answer (score 4):

Thanks!

I also RTFM'd the TortoiseSVN FAQ which notes that you can right-click and select Properties... (Windows Properties not SVN Properties) and click on the "Subversion" tab to view the URL (and other interesting things).

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the working folder -> Repo Browser

Whatever path loads in the URL is where it was checked out from.